# Inequality with a twice differentiable function

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a twice differentiable function.
$f''(x)>0$ for every $x\in \mathbb R$.
Prove for every $x\in \mathbb R$:
$\frac{f(x+1)+f(x-1)}{2}>f(x)$

I was trying to use MVT but then I got stuck after not being able to get to the right side of the inequality.

Answer (score 1):

A function with $f''(x)>0$ is *strictly convex* and that implies the desired conclusion.

For a direct proof consider for a fixed $x \in \Bbb R$ the function
$$
 g(h) = f(x+h) + f(x-h) \, .
$$
Show that

- $g''(h) > 0$ for all $h \in \Bbb R$.
- $g'(h) > g'(0) = 0$ for $h > 0$.
- $f(x+1)+f(x-1) = g(1) > g(0) = 2f(x)$.